# I want my program to run again and again without getting stop

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
public class bad {

        public static void main(String []args)
    {
            Scanner input;
            input = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("Enter First Num ");
        int a =input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Secound Num ");
        int b =input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("For Addition press a" );
        System.out.println("For Subtraction press s" );
        System.out.println("For Multiplication press m" );
        System.out.println("For Divide press d" );
        System.out.println("For Square and Cube press c" );
        //the Square and cube depend apone you wither you have to Square or cube.
        System.out.println("For Root press r");
        String store =input.nextLine();

        if (store .equals("a"))


    {

        System.out.print("Answear is: ");
        System.out.print(a+b);
    }
        else if(store .equals("m"))
    {
        System.out.print("Answear is: ");
        System.out.print(a*b);
    }

        else if(store .equals("d"))
    {   
        System.out.print("Answear is: ");
        System.out.print(a/b);
    }
        else if(store .equals("s"))
    {
        System.out.print("Answear is: ");
        System.out.print(a-b);
    }


        else if(store .equals("c"))
        {   

        System.out.println("Answear for the power is : ");
        System.out.print(Math.pow(a,b));
    }
        else if (store.equals("r"))
        {
            System.out.println("Answear is : ");
            System.out.println(Math.sqrt(a));
        }




        }
    }
```

my program to run again and again without getting stop means that the program ask the user to Enter a number again?
Have search lot but not getting the basic idea.May be while loop will work but have use it twice not getting it .

Comment: New user, new programmer - be nice guys.

Comment: *Note* : **Do not** make titles like that , have it concise & clear

Comment: If you've tried a while loop, then post your attempt using the while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using something like this,

```
boolean run = true;

while(run) {

   //when the condition to terminate the program is met
   //set run to false
   run = false;
}
```

Comment: Something like this would work. Just tell the user to enter 'q' or 'quit' to terminate the program, then check to see if they have entered either so you can set your run flag.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(true){

//your complete code
}
```

Try to use while loop again like